# How to enable/disable spdlog logging in code?

Tags: c++, spdlog

I am creating c++ library modules in my application.  To do logging, I use [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog).  But in a production environment, I don't want my lib modules to do any logging.  One way to achieve turning on/off would be to litter my code with #ifdef conditionals like...

```
#ifdef logging
  // call the logger here.
#endif
```

I am looking for a way to avoid writing these conditionals.  May be a wrapper function that does the #ifdef checking and write it.  But the problem with this approach is that I have to write wrappers for every logging method (such as info, trace, warn, error, ...)

Is there a better way?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/1.-QuickStart#debugtrace-macros

Answer (score 10):

You can disable logging with `set_level()`:

```
auto my_logger = spdlog::basic_logger_mt("basic_logger", "logs/basic.txt");

#if defined(PRODUCTION)
    my_logger->set_level(spdlog::level::off);
#else
    my_logger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
#endif

spdlog::register_logger(my_logger);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can disable all logging before you compile the code by adding the following macro (before including spdlog.h):

```
#define SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL SPDLOG_LEVEL_OFF
#include<spdlog.h>
```

It is explained as a comment in the file https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/v1.x/include/spdlog/spdlog.h :

```
//
// enable/disable log calls at compile time according to global level.
//
// define SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL to one of those (before including spdlog.h):
// SPDLOG_LEVEL_TRACE,
// SPDLOG_LEVEL_DEBUG,
// SPDLOG_LEVEL_INFO,
// SPDLOG_LEVEL_WARN,
// SPDLOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
// SPDLOG_LEVEL_CRITICAL,
// SPDLOG_LEVEL_OFF
//
```

Using this macro will also speed up your productive code because the logging calls are completely erased from your code. Therefore this approach may be better than using `my_logger->set_level(spdlog::level::off);`

However, in order for the complete code removal to work you need to use either of the macros when logging:

```
SPDLOG_LOGGER_###(logger, ...)

SPDLOG_###(...)
```

where `###` is one of `TRACE`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`, `CRITICAL`.

The latter macro uses the default logger `spdlog::default_logger_raw()`, the former can be used with your custom loggers. The variadic arguments `...` stand for the regular arguments to your logging invocation: the fmt string, followed by some values to splice into the message.

Comment: I don't know if I have an old version, but to write TRACE and DEBUG (not for others levels), I need to add ```spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::###);``` in my code.

Comment: @Kafka: That is correct. The macro SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL sets the "highest available log level" at compile time. The level actually logged at runtime is still affected by what your logger instance has chosen at runtime (e.g. via "spdlog::set_level"). In other words, your final log level will always be the maximum of SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL and what you have set with "spdlog::set_level". Since the default level for the latter is INFO, you did not see DEBUG and TRACE messages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know spdlog.

However, you may define a macro in one of your common used include file, to replace the logcall by nothing, or a call to an empty inline function which the compiler optimizer will eliminate.

in "app.h"

```
#ifndef LOG

#ifdef logging
#define LOG spdlog
#endif

#ifndef logging
#define LOG noop
#endif

#endif
```

Did you get the idea?

This let most of your code untouched

Comment: Yes, thx. As I checked, it works for plain functions. But if spdlog is a class which has member fns like trace(), info() etc, it doesn't compile.

Comment: I think the approach should also work with classes. Please document how your current code looks like. Maybe me or other supply you with other approaches